# Why couldn't Hrathen force his odiv’s odivs to stay?

Tags: cosmere, elantris

In the book *Elantris*, when Hrathen starts to get suspicious of Dilaf, he decides to send him away for a couple of weeks on a "mission". Dilaf, being one step ahead, made all of Hrathen's closest arteths (priests) into his odiv – which means they are completely subservient to him. He then told Hrathen that if he goes, he'll take all of his odivs with him.

The problem is that Dilaf, being an odiv to Hrathen has to obey anything he says, so theoretically, if Hrathen were to tell Dilaf to tell *his* odivs to stay behind, he should *have* to tell them?

Comment: Are you confusing the **social hierarchy** within the temple (i.e. "arteths are *supposed* to obey their odivs") for **domination of the will** (i.e. "arteths *have no choice* about whether they will obey their odivs").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may have been there was some protocol that prevented Hrathen from making such an order, I cannot recall. But even if there was not, it was abundantly clear that Dilaf was challenging Hrathen by saying he would take his odivs with him. There would definitely have been political ramifications if Hrathen had pushed on the issue.

For instance, by the implied threat by Dilaf, it seemed likely that if Hrathen had made such an order, Dilaf would defy him. Now, we know that in reality Dilaf was a gragdet, and so likely would have pulled rank or used his rank to defy Hrathen in some way. But Hrathen was unaware of Dilaf's real rank, and so the threat would have seemed to him to mean that he would defy Hrathen's orders. This would cause a huge problem for him for multiple reasons:  1.  All of Dilaf's odivs would either have to defy Dilaf, putting their new faith at risk because they would be technically breaking the rules, or they will still follow his orders to the same bad result 2.  He would now be "at war" with Dilaf, and having to deal with that as well as still needing to convert Arelon.

Therefore, I believe Hrathen decided it was best to rescind his order.

Answer (score 1):

it says in the book that it is against protocol to interfere in what an odiv tells his odiv to do.

> It was well within Dilaf's power to make his odivs accompany him to Fjorden. Hrathen could have no control over what the arteth did with his sworn followers; it would be a grave breach of protocol to order Dilaf to leave them behind.

Answer (score 1):

### Essentially, it would break the rules of the hroden-odiv bonds that Hrathen follows so vigorously. Even if it were within his abilities, it would be abuse of his power.

Hrathen is very, very devout about following rules within the Derethi bureaucracy, so he won’t do that, as Dilaf apparently understands. I guess that all levels of the hroden-odiv relationship are supposed to be respected, so one hroden above wouldn’t be allowed to interfere with the control of odivs a step below according to traditions.

Relevant quote (emphasis added):

> It was well within Dilaf’s power to make his odivs accompany him to Fjorden. **Hrathen could have no control over what the stretch did with his sworn followers; it would be a grave breach of protocol** to order Dilaf to leave them behind.
>
> <sub>Chapter 21 (page 299 in my 2006 American first mass market edition)</sub>